# Preventing a build from running on the same node if it failed previously in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Any plugins or default behavior in Jenkins that I could configure to force a build to be done on a different node if the previous build on a node was a failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it appears there are not many plugins that allow you control over jobs running on Jenkins nodes and none that do this.